# StreamPlot and VectorPlot handling of functions with singularities

Tags: plotting, singularity

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica's `Plot` can handle plotting functions with singularities

From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html

> You can plot functions that have singularities. The Wolfram Language
>   will try to choose appropriate scales.

But `StreamPlot` and `VectorPlot` do not.

I am trying to plot functions using `StreamPlot`, but I do not know beforehand what these functions are, other than they depend on `x` and `y`. Some of them can have singularity at origin or somewhere else.

I selected a small region around the origin. Here is an example

```
ClearAll[f,x,y];
f = (2*x*y)/(x^2 - y^2);
StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also `Exclusions` option is not supported by `StreamPlot`

What would be the correct way to `StreamPlot` such functions and avoiding `1/0` error?

Comment: You still get the (correct) plot though. Right ?

Comment: @Lotus Yes, the plots comes out. Sorry I did not mention this. I just need a way to do it without the error message coming out, like with the `Plot` command.

Comment: Nasser, does this work for you: `dom = FunctionDomain[f,  {x, y}];
StreamPlot[{1, If[dom, f]}, {x, -2,2},{y,-2,2}]`?

Comment: Maybe try `Quiet`?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Yes, I know this is an option always, but I was hoping to see if there is a less brute force method. For me `Quiet` feels like hiding the main issue under the cover. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr Yes, that worked! nice solution. if you like to post it as possible answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, x, y];
f = (2*x*y)/(x^2 - y^2);
dom = FunctionDomain[f, {x, y}];
StreamPlot[{1, If[dom, f]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]